# How to scrape website with mouseover events and no class on most elements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table with data off a website with mouse-over color changing events and on each row only the first two columns have a class:
[image: Elements]

Additionally, when I do try to scrape those first two rows I get the output as such:
[image: Output]

This is the code I am running.

```py
lists = soup.find_all('table', class_= "report")

for list in lists:
    date = list.find_all('td', class_= "time")
    flag = list.find_all('td', class_= "flag")
    info = [date, flag]
    print(info)
```

I was expecting to receive only the numerical values so that I can export them and work with them.
I tried to use the `.replace()` function but it didn't remove anything.
I was unable to use `.text` even after converting date and flag to strings.

Comment: Well date and flag themselves will return list objects which `.replace()` will not work on unless you access the particular item that you want to look at. (secondly you shouldn't name something `list` as that is a function keyword to turn elements into a list, instead do something like list_item in you for loop or just simply item) It is unclear what the problem / what you are doing to advise what you should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Notes

It might be better to not use `list` as a variable name since it already means something in python....

Also, I can't test any of the suggestions below without having access to your HTML. It would be helpful if you include how you fetched the HTML to parse with BeautifulSoup. (Did you use some form of requests? Or something like selenium? Or do you just have the HTML file?) With requests or even selenium, sometimes the HTML fetched is not what you expected, so that's another issue...

---

##### The Reason behind the Issue

You can't apply `.text`/`.get_text` to the ResultSets (lists), which are what `.find_all` and `.select` return. You *can* apply `.text`/`.get_text` to Tags like the ones returned by **`.find`** or **`.select_one`** (but you should check first `None` was not returned - which happens when nothing is found).

So `date[0].get_text()` might have returned something, but since you probably want all the dates and flags, that's not the solution.

---

##### Solution Part 1 Option A: Getting the Rows with `.find...` chain

Instead of iterating through tables directly, you need to get the rows first (`tr` tags) before trying to get at the cells (`td` tags); if you have only one `table` with `class= "report"`, you could just do something like:

```py
rows = soup.find('table', class_= "report").find_all('tr',  {'onmouseover': True})
```

But it's risky to chain multiple `.find...`s like that, because an error will be raised if any of them return `None` before reaching the last one.

---

##### Solution Part 1 Option B: Getting the Rows More Safely with `.find...`

It would be safer to do something like

```py
table = soup.find('table', class_= "report")
rows = table.find_all('tr',  {'onmouseover': True}) if table else []
```

or, if there might be more than one `table` with `class= "report"`,

```py
rows = []
for table in soup.find_all('table', class_= "report"): 
    rows += table.find_all('tr',  {'onmouseover': True})
```

---

##### Solution Part 1 Option C: Getting the Rows with `.select`

However, I think the most convenient way is to use [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

```py
# if there might be other tables with report AND other classes that you don't want:
# rows = soup.select('table[class="report"] tr[onmouseover]') 

rows = soup.select('table.report tr[onmouseover]')
```

this method is only unsuitable if there might be more than one `table` with `class= "report"`, but you only want rows from the first one; in that case, you might prefer the *`table.find_....if table else []`* approach.

---

##### Solution Part 2 Option A: Iterating Over `rows` to Print Cell Contents

Once you have `rows`, you can iterate over them to print the date and flag cell contents:

```py
for r in rows:
    date, flag = r.find('td', class_= "time"), r.find('td', class_= "flag")
    info = [i.get_text() if i else i for i in [date, flag]]
    if any([i is not None for i in info]): print(info) 
    # [ only prints if there are any non-null values ]
```

---

##### Solution Part 2 Option B: Iterating Over `rows` with a Fucntion

Btw, if you're going to be extracting multiple tag attributes/texts repeatedly, you might find my [`selectForList`](https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u) function useful - it could have been used like

```py
for r in rows: 
    info = selectForList(r, ['td.time', 'td.flag'], printList=True)
    if any([i is not None for i in info]): print(info)
```

or, to get a list of dictionaries like *`[{'time': time_1, 'flag': flag_1}, {'time': time_2, 'flag': flag_2}, ...]`*,

```py
infList = [selectForList(r, {
    'time': 'td.time', 'flag': 'td.flag', ## add selectors for any info you want 
}) for r in soup.select('table.report tr[onmouseover]')]
infList = [d for d in infoList if [v for v in d.values() if v is not None]]
```

---

##### Added EDIT:

To get all displayed cell contents:

```py
for r in rows: 
    info = [(td.get_text(),''.join(td.get('style','').split())) for td in r.select('td')]
    info = [txt.strip() for txt, styl in r.select('td') if 'display:none' not in styl]
    # info = [i if i else 0 for i in info] # fill blanks with zeroes intead of ''
    if any(info):  print(info) ## or write to CSV
```

Comment: The site has some proprietary data and requires login which is why I didn't want to include it. Should have included these though, apologies.
```python
response = requests.get('https://vector.propreports.com/report.php', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```
Also forgot to mention that the website requires login. I used cookies for that but I suspect I will need to change it in order to automate as the site kicks you out after a while.

Comment: the ```python
table = soup.find('table', class_= "report")
rows = table.find_all('tr',  {'onmouseover': True}) if table else []```
works for the whole table but still get all the "<td class="time">05/11/22</td>
<td class="flag">Eq</td>" etc.

Comment: I was unable to use selectForList as I am still very much clueless to many intricacies of additional modules etc. Your version, however, gave me a great output, pretty much exactly what I need but again only for the first two columns. [link]https://imgur.com/3LXa4Mr

Comment: @tracemuch did you iterate over rows [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPsQc.png) or as suggested in the last section? (Just in case it was unclear, I re-structured my answer sections - you need an option from part 1 followed by an option from part 2 for any full solution)

Comment: @tracemuch that's great! as for `selectForList`, although you could download into a file (let's say "selectForList.py") and then do something like `from selectForList import selectForList` (or`from selectForList import *` to use both fuctions inside), I usually just paste it into the code right after the imports (it may be easier to paste [from the raw](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZnZ7xM6u), although if you use PasteBin yourself you might see [the `copy` button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziszd.png))....it's not so important though, if you have v few details you want to extract like just flag+date

Comment: I spent all day updating the code and now I have a working automated login with credentials instead of cookies and integrated your code for the first two columns. If I just manage to scrape the rest of the table I will have all the data I need to work on. Any ideas how I can finish this? https://imgur.com/4EulRjq

Comment: @tracemuch (It might be better to post a separate question for that, with a html snippet [pasteable, not just a screenshot] containing at least 2 *relevant* `tr` tags, preferably as different as they can get from each other, and also maybe a sample of the desired output...) but based on the `tr` in your screenshot, I guess you could first try adding a line **`info += [td.get_text().strip() for td in r.select('td:not([class]):not([style])') if td.get_text().strip()]`** right before the *`if any(...): print(info)`* line and see if that leads to the results you want

Comment: Absolutely! One last thing I'm struggling with. There are blank spaces in some rows which cause the data to be structured weird when I try to write it to a file: https://imgur.com/v2vT2on How can I for example output "0" for every blank cell or alternatively restructure how the .csv is written. This is what I have so far: https://imgur.com/qqKH1ZV How the CSV looks: https://imgur.com/4Jfy8lk

Comment: Example of 6 blank cells before the next entry: https://imgur.com/0C67HlM

Comment: @tracemuch get rid of the ` if td.get_text().strip()` part (of  *`info += ...`*) if you don't want to skip blank cells, and add another line right after *`info += ...`*  with **`info = [i if i else 0 for i in info]`** to replace blanks

Comment: @tracemuch now that I've seen the blank cells that you might want, and that some of the the wanted cells can have `style` attribute, I think you should change the selector in *`info += ...`* to **`td:not([class]):not([style*="display:none"]):not([style*="display: none"])`**

Comment: @tracemuch or just change the whole line to `info += [td.get_text().strip() for td in r.select('td:not([class])') if 'display:none' not in td.get('style', '').replace(' ', '')]`

Comment: @tracemuch actually, you can just have `info = [td.get_text().strip() for td in r.select('td') if 'display:none' not in td.get('style', '').replace(' ', '')]` and skip the first two lines in the *`for r in rows:...`* block [I'm adding in an edit to the answer]

Comment: @ Driftr95 The first solution worked perfectly! You are amazing, my friend! Thank you again!